# Generate a list of unique random numbers where the number should not be same as index of number in list using kdb

Tags: kdb

I need to write a function that generates a list of unique random numbers where the number should not be the same as the index of the list.

```
Valid output - 1 3 2 0  
Invalid output - 0 3 2 1 /- Number 0 and index 0 are same
Invalid output - 1 0 2 3 /- Number 2 and 3 matches with index
```

I can think of using deal function(?) but the numbers in the list match with the index

```
-5?5
```

Can I do something with the seed so that it generates numbers different from the index of the number?
  Any other solution without roll/deal function(?) also will be of great help.

EDIT:
I came up with below solution - (Different/optimized approaches are welcome)

```
{$[max(til x)=o:{neg[x]?x}x;.z.s[x];o]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to do go about this. I came up with this:

```
q){$[any (r:neg[x]?x)=til x;.z.s x;r]}5
3 2 4 0 1
q){$[any (r:neg[x]?x)=til x;.z.s x;r]}5
2 0 4 1 3
```

Generates your random list then if any of the indexes match it will generate another list until no indexes match.

Comment: Depending on your preference you can turn this into a converge, something like: {neg[x]?x}/[{x~til count x}$;5]